# Get All Columns with Table Information from Teradata DB

Tags: sql, teradata, ddl

This one works, producing the column names only:

```
SELECT ColumnName 
FROM dbc.columnsV
WHERE DatabaseName = 'DB_NAME';
```

**but** I want to see the table name and the column type as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... This one was an easy one, I managed to answer it myself:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbc.columnsV
WHERE DatabaseName = 'DB_NAME';
```

produces the needed table with all the stuff that one may need, including these columns:

```
DatabaseName
TableName
ColumnName
ColumnFormat
ColumnTitle
SPParameterType
ColumnType
ColumnUDTName
ColumnLength
DefaultValue
Nullable
CommentString
DecimalTotalDigits
DecimalFractionalDigits
ColumnId
UpperCaseFlag
Compressible
CompressValue
ColumnConstraint
ConstraintCount
CreatorName
CreateTimeStamp
LastAlterName
LastAlterTimeStamp
CharType
IdColType
AccessCount
LastAccessTimeStamp
CompressValueList
TimeDimension
VTCheckType
TTCheckType
ConstraintId
ArrayColNumberOfDimensions
ArrayColScope
ArrayColElementType
ArrayColElementUdtName
PartitioningColumn
ColumnPartitionNumber
ColumnPartitionFormat
ColumnPartitionAC
PseudoUDTFieldId
PseudoUDTFieldType
StorageFormat
DatasetSchemaName
InlineLength
TSColumnType
AutoColumn
RowVersionNo
```

So, the needed query is:

```
SELECT DatabaseName, TABLENAME, ColumnName, ColumnType
FROM dbc.columnsV
WHERE DatabaseName = 'DB_NAME';
```